# orchestral / testbench getPackageAliases() not working on github actions

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

When testing with the orchestral testbench Im binding my own class to `App\Models\User` in the base `TestCase`:

```php
protected function getPackageAliases($app)
{
    return [
        'App\Models\User' => 'DataStory\Tests\Fake\App\Models\User',
    ];
}
```

To test this setup I have this test

```php
public function test_fake_models()
{
    $this->assertInstanceOf(
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::class,
        \App\Models\User::query()
    );
}
```

The test works fine when running locally. But on github actions:

> ErrorException: Class "DataStory\Tests\Fake\App\Models\User" not found

All other tests not depending on the faked User works.

Here is my github actions script: `.github/workflows/test.yml`

```
name: tests

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout the package
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install
      run: composer install

    - name: Run tests
      run: ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests
```

Did I miss something I need to configure in the testbench or what can be my issue?

Comment: The workflow: https://github.com/ajthinking/data-story/blob/master/.github/workflows/tests.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you use Windows which has CI FS (case insensitive filesystem). Ubuntu/GH Actions use CS FS.

You must adjust the case (at least rename `app/Models` to `App/Models`, see https://github.com/ajthinking/data-story/tree/master/tests/Fake).